# Data Pipeline: Stop creating empty file in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-data-pipeline

I am using AWS data pipeline to take backup of RDS table data on certain condition and store that backup CSV file in S3 bucket. It's working fine when there is data to backup but when there is no data then also data pipeline is creating empty file in S3. Is there any was to stop creating empty files in S3?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add more background information on how you are using pipeline?  Is this an automated job?  What kicks off your job?  are you scripting it using a certain language/platform? via console? CLI? SDK?  We can help you, we just need more details....put more details and this should be easy to solve:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Taterhead A good example is the template "Incremental copy of RDS MySQL table to S3" that can be scheduled every hour for example.

Comment: what's the select statement used in the template?